# Multivalue parameter as vbscript function input in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to modify following code, which gives value for query in report file. Old one works if there is finite number of values, modified should be universal for any number of values.

```
<Value>=Switch(Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=1, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=2, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=3, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=4, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=5, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=6, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=7, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=8, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=9, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=10, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=11, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=12, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=13, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=14, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(13) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=15, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(14) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(13) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=16, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(15) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(14) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(13) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=17, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(16) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(15) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(14) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(13) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=18, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(17) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(16) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(15) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(14) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(13) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=19, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(18) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(17) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(16) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(15) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(14) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(13) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
,Parameters!TagHum.Count-20=20, Parameters!TagHum.Value(0) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(19) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(18) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(17) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(16) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(15) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(14) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(13) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(12) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(11) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(10) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(9) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(8) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(7) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(6) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(5) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(4) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(3) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(2) & ";" & Parameters!TagHum.Value(1)
) </Value>
```

It could be solved by for cycle, but SSRS dont support cycles, so i think i could include vbs file with function like this:

```
    Public Shared Function TagTempHum_parse(Param_count,Param_values)
    Dim arr1()
    Dim result
    Dim TagCount = Param_count - 20
    Dim i = 0
    For i = 1 To TagCount
        result = result & Param_values(i) & ";"
    Next
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    TagTempHum_parse = result
    End Function
```

and in SSRS call this function:

```
<Value>
=Code.TagTempHum_parse(Parameters!TagHum.Count,Parameters!TagHum.Value)
</Value>
```

My first question is: Is this method even possible?
Second problem: I need to pass all Parameters!TagHumValue values to function, how can I do this when I dont know how many are there?

Sorry if my questions are dumb, Im new in SSRS. Will be glad for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to put your parameter selections in a single string?

You can use **JOIN** to put them into a single text line:

```
=Join(Parameters!TagHum.Value, ";")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: This completely solved my problem, nice and simple...thanks Hannover